# Tabbing trough accordion component does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an accordion component which works fine, but recently I notice that when I start tabbing trough the component is not working as expected.

Here is my code:

```
<ul>
  <li tabindex="0">
    <h4 aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="abc" id="id_abc">
      <span>My Title 1</span>
    </h4>
    <div id="abc" role="region" aria-labelledby="id_abc">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://google.com">Link a1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link a2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li tabindex="0">
    <h4 aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="xyz" id="id_xyz">
      <span>My Title 2</span>
    </h4>
    <div id="xyz" role="region" aria-labelledby="id_xyz">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://google.com">Link b1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://google.com">Link b2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The issue here is that when I'm tabbing trough, I suppose to go over `My title 1` and skip to `My title 2` because none of them are open. (by the way the `aria-expanded` changes without any problem) but when I go to `My Title 1` closed it goes deeper trough `Link a1` and `Link a2` same as going trough `My Title 2`. Does anyone know why am I getting this behavior?

**NOTE**: I discover that when I changed the `<a>` tag for a `<p>` or simple text it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some items are focuseable by default, these are:

- Links ()
- Form input elements such as text boxes, checkboxes, radio buttons, and buttons
- Content-editable elements `<div contenteditable="true">`, `<span contenteditable="true">`

If your markup has good semantics, eg. things you can click on are buttons, you wont have to worry too much about tabindex.

However, depending on how you are hiding the acordion content, that could also affect tabindex.

For example, an element with `display: none` will be skipped when tabbing through the page. `visibility: hidden` will still recieve focus.

For usability sake, it is often considered good practice that focuseable elements are elements you can interact with.

Comment: display: none did the magic.